How to set HDD/SSD core settings without hdparm?
I'd like to set the idle timeout of a hybrid-SSD/HDD and am surprised to read the Arch Wiki saying to install hdparm as the starting point to set disk software settings.
Does that mean some distributions are set in some way but don't provide the mean to control it?
Or that in 2024 other tools have replaced hdparm, then why is hdparm the first result appearing?

What do you mean by "don't provide the mean to control it"? The hdparm tool is readily available, just like any other utility that you may want to use on your system (and the wiki says the first step is to install it from the core package repository). Note, too, that the wiki prominently warns you about changing the disk's default parameters, as that may corrupt the disk.

The timeouts adjustable with hdparm are not implemented by the operating system, but by the disk itself: by its own hardware and firmware.
Disk manufacturers generally intend their products to be usable as-is, without any further tweaking; but if the disk contains adjustable settings, they might provide (often Windows-only) tools that can adjust them.
Since not all Linux systems dual-boot with Windows, that is obviously inadequate for Linux users. So the Linux community has had to re-implement their own version of such configuration tools. Since all such tools are based on sending special ATA/SATA/SCSI commands to the disk, and hdparm already has the infrastructure to send such commands, implementing the ability to tweak such adjustments as patches to hdparm has become the common solution.
Over the years, hdparm has become the main collection point of esoteric, vendor-specific and otherwise rarely used disk features. It is no longer the IDE/ATA-specific tool of the era of the Linux 2.0/2.2 kernels. And it is not an obsolete tool by any means.
Most distributions provide hdparm as an optional package: you'd install it only if you need it.
But you asked how to adjust the idle timeout without hdparm. You're in luck: it appears that smartctl seems to duplicate that bit of functionality, if you are somehow philosophically opposed to hdparm. See man smartctl for the full description of smartctl --get=all, smartctl --set=aam,<value>, smartctl --set=apm,<value> and smartctl --set=standby,<value>.

I have none of hdparm nor smartctl installed. Finally, I used gnome-disk which provides an access to the Disk Parameters > Idle mode . I don't know how it does under the hood, maybe direct SMART commands. Nothing to install is always better.

hdparm is a small command-line tool that has no service components persistently running and no setuid/setgid or otherwise privilege-granting binaries associated with it, so I would consider the risk as minimal. In principle, though, you're entirely correct. Good to know that gnome-disk has that feature, although I'm more of a KDE guy myself.
